# CSS variables in SVG stopped working on iOS 16.4.1

Tags: html, css, svg

So I have an svg file that I embed to my page with this pattern:

```html
<svg><use href="svg_css_test.svg#test"></use></svg>
```

It refers some css variables like this:

```html
<circle
  style="fill:var(--circle_color);stroke:none;"
  cx="18.520834"
  cy="6.6145835"
  r="5.2916665" />
```

It works perfectly with other platforms and browsers, and it also worked on iOS 16.3, but went wrong with 16.4.1. The css variables are just ignored. If I just copy the svg content to the html file, it works, but I'd like keep the svg separated since it's used at several places.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this situation?

Test page: https://kovacsv.hu/test

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=255985

Comment: You need to define --circle-color. Try this: `style="--circle_color:red; fill:var(--circle_color); stroke:none;"`

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson I was not able to find it, hopefully it will be fixed soon.